# Switch onclick Event onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I have a function written to open / close a div using a placeholder for a hyperlink.

```
<a class="button" onclick="show('click-drop')">Open</a>
```

The `onclick` event then opens the div.

I have this `onclick` to close it:

```
<a class="button" onclick="hide('click-drop')">Close</a>
```

What I would like to do is have a single placeholder for a hyperlink that switches between the two `onclick` events. So `onclick=show` would switch to `onclick=hide` and vice versa.

I have looked everywhere and cannot find a straightforward solution for my situation.

### Revised Question

Here's specifically what I am working with.

```
function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.height = '300px';
}
function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.height = '0px';
}

<a class="button" onclick="show('click-drop')">Open</a>
<div id="click-drop" style="height:0px">
    <a class="button" onclick="hide('click-drop')">Close</a>
</div>
```

Click `Open` and it opens / expands inline height style. Click `Close` and it closes.

**I need to have the `onclick` toggle, but with `Open` changing to `Close` and reverse.**

It would be ideal to keep the placement of the links. So the `Open` link outside the link is hidden until the `Close` link within the div is clicked.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997687/javascript-hiding-and-showing-div-tag-with-a-toggle-button

Comment: @StuFu I've edited the question. I don't believe it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You could dynamically change the `onclick` event of the button, but it's already awkward enough that you're using HTML to describe functionality. It would do you even better if you kept all functionality in the JavaScript. Something like this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var target = document.getElementById("target");

button.innerHTML = "Close";
button.onclick = function() { hide(target); };

function hide(target) {
  console.log("hiding");
  target.style.display = "none";
  console.log(target);
  button.innerHTML = "Open";
  button.onclick = function() { show(target); };
}

function show(target) {
  target.style.display = "block";
  button.innerHTML = "Close";
  button.onclick = function() { hide(target); };
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Close</button>
<div id="target">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: I've posted a second answer if you want more reusability out of `hide` and `show`. I think it may even be a better answer than this first answer, but I'll let the community decide.

Comment: So I am reading up a little on what you've suggested. Because I am not using unobtrusive JS I am limited in some aspects. But it's a little above my head ATM. I can't run a jsfiddle because of this reason :/

Comment: @jarmerson I've made my code into a snippet so that you can run it, if that is what you mean.

Comment: My answer below will clarify what I meant. I'm referencing my own code.

Comment: @jarmerson Ohh, I think I understand now. To use JS in the HTML in a jsfiddle, use a <script> tag in the HTML. Then it will be able to "see" the JS.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with my specific example - https://jsfiddle.net/jarmerson/c43xxeLx/3/ - I've tried several variations of options there too. Obviously this is new to me.

Comment: Here's what I meant: I modified [your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c43xxeLx/5/)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you. I will tackle these other two things after some shut eye.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another answer in case you want to use `toggle` on multiple buttons. This solution uses the button to store the state of its target, and so it uses `toggle.call()` to modify the value of `this` within `toggle`.

It's inspired by [`jQuery.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [Yuriy Yakym's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37233478/5743988).

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  var button = document.getElementById("button"+i),
      target = document.getElementById("target"+i);
  // wrapped in closure because https://stackoverflow.com/q/8909652/5743988
  (function(_button, _target) {
    _button.onclick = function() {
      toggle.call(_button, _target);
    }
  })(button, target);
}

function toggle(target) {
  this.func = this.func || hide; // if "func" is undefined, assign "hide"
  this.func.call(target); // execute "func"
  this.func = this.func === hide // make "func" call the other thing next time
    ? (this.innerHTML = "Show", show) : (this.innerHTML = "Hide", hide);
}

function hide() {
  this.oldDisplay = window.getComputedStyle(this).display;
  this.style.display = "none"; // better than "height = 0px"
}

function show() {
  this.oldDisplay = this.oldDisplay || "block";
  this.style.display = this.oldDisplay;
}
```

```css
button, div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Close</button>
<div id="target1">Hello World!</div>
<br>
<button id="button2">Close</button>
<div id="target2">Hello Again World!</div>
<br>
<button id="button3">Close</button>
<div id="target3">Hello Again Again World!</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your insight @4castle. The answers here helped. I did figure out a hack of sorts that works perfectly, but may be improved upon. See my answer below. Maybe you can help with the two questions it raises. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to save button's state inside its context. And then, depending on its state call appropriate functions.

```js
function toggle() {
    this.state = !this.state; // false - open; true - closed; default = false (because is not initialized yet)
    this.innerHTML = this.state ? 'Close' : 'Open';
    
    if(this.state) {
        open();
    } else {
        close();
    }
}

function open() {
    alert("Opened");
}

function close() {
    alert("Closed");
}
```

```html
<a class="button" onclick="toggle.call(this)">Open</a>
<a class="button" onclick="toggle.call(this)">Open</a>
<a class="button" onclick="toggle.call(this)">Open</a>
```

Comment: I think you flipped `open` and `close`. Close is supposed to be first I believe. This is really awesome! You might also want to store the target element in the button's context too so that `toggle` is reusable for other buttons without having to repeatedly call `document.getElement...`.

Comment: This works as expected but it wasn't suitable for my specific need. It's pretty cool though - will make use of it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Either the [jQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) methods should the trick for you.

Edit, per requested, an example:

Say you have a CSS class that looks like this, based on the OP:

```
.info-box { 
    height: 300px;
}
```

By using `$('#myTarget').toggleClass('info-box')`, you will be removing that class or adding it. If you don't have it, you'll add it. If you do have it, you'll remove it. Just like that.

So, a working example I just threw together is here, and it implements `toggle()` by itself without the need to add any classes, which I believe still accomplishes what the OP was seeking resolution for.

https://jsfiddle.net/bbh9m478/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: As is, this isn't an answer to the question. At best, it's a link to the answer. Can you elaborate? Or make a comment.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to write examples when typing on your smartphone. :) Just got to a laptop and added examples and a working jsFiddle. Hope that clarifies a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a straightforward solution for this.

When the open link is clicked and the div opens I need the open link to disappear and a close link displayed as a separate element. The same event should work in reverse i.e. close link closes div and displays open link.

While the original code I am working with uses an inline height property to control the open and close, the example below uses display property.

```
function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}
function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
function hideButton() {
    var x = document.getElementById("open");
    x.style.display = "none";
    var x = document.getElementById("close");
    x.style.display = "";
}
function showButton() {
    var x = document.getElementById("open");
    x.style.display = "";
    var x = document.getElementById("close");
    x.style.display = "none";
}

<a class="button" onclick="show('click-drop');hideButton()" id="open">Open</a>

<div id="click-drop" style="display:none">

<a class="button" onclick="hide('click-drop');showButton()" id="close" style="display:none">Close</a>

</div>
```

Here it is in the wild - http://iemajen.com/scripts/mssa/

With this in place I have two more questions.

1. How would I write this so it uses unobtrusive Javascript to attach behaviour to DOM elements from within the JS solely, meaning separate HTML from JS
2. How can I write this to be used on multiple divs? I have a dozen divs that will be closed initially and each opened individually using the markup I wrote. I could write it up for each div / unique ids and such, but that seems like more bad practice and I would like to learn the best practice.

Should I just open a new topic for the last question?

Comment: To answer you first question, see what I did in my first answer. To answer your second question, give additional parameters to `hideButton` and `showButton` so that they will be reusable for many buttons. The parameter you add should be the id of the two buttons, or you can pass the buttons themselves as the parameter.

Comment: @4castle you gave me great direction. I've written it up so it's unobtrusive - https://jsfiddle.net/jarmerson/e2fexbqp/ - now I am unclear on how to give additional parameters so I can use the buttons in multiple instances along side an equal number of divs. I've played around without luck.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your element

`var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
var init = new Switchery(elem);`

Bind your `OnClickMetod` to `init.switcher` like this

`$(init.switcher).on('click', OnClickMetod);`