# javascript/html: Second onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image - image1.png. When I click a button the first time, I want it to change to image2.png. When I click the button for a second time, I want it to change to another image, image3.png.

So far I've got it to change to image2 perfectly, was easy enough. I'm just stuck finding a way to change it a second time.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="image" src="image1.png"/>

<button onclick=changeImage()>Click me!</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function changeImage(){

document.getElementById("image").src="image2.png";

}
```

I'm aware I can change the image source with HTML within the button code, but I believe it'll be cleaner with a JS function. I'm open to all solutions though.

Comment: use `addEventListener`

Comment: check the value of the src attribute in the click handler then change it accordingly

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997687/javascript-hiding-and-showing-div-tag-with-a-toggle-button) might help

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a counter to bump up the image number. Just set the `maxCounter` variable to the highest image number you plan to use.

Also, note that this code removes the inline HTML event handler, which is a very outdated way of hooking HTML up to JavaScript. It is not recommended because it actually creates a global wrapper function around your callback code and doesn't follow the W3C DOM Level 2 event handling standards. It also doesn't follow the "separation of concerns" methodology for web development. It's must better to use `.addEventListener` to hook up your DOM elements to events.

```js
// Wait until the document is fully loaded...,
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

  // Now, it's safe to scan the DOM for  the elements needed
  var b = document.getElementById("btnChange");
  var i = document.getElementById("image");

  var imgCounter = 2; // Initial value to start with
  var maxCounter = 3; // Maximum value used

  // Wire the button up to a click event handler:
  b.addEventListener("click", function(){

    // If we haven't reached the last image yet...
    if(imgCounter <= maxCounter){
      i.src = "image" + imgCounter + ".png";
      console.log(i.src);
      imgCounter++;
    }
  });
  
});  // End of window.addEventListener()
```

```html
<img id="image" src="image1.png">

<button id="btnChange">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: this solution assumes there is infinite number of images but original question says there is just three... what if user clicks 1972 times?

Comment: @AykutAteş As my answer states "If you have an upper limit for the number, just aded if/then logic around the `imgCounter++` code."

Comment: @AykutAteş Add the simple `if(cnt<=3){ // than do something }` it will solve the issue

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar obviously, but still this answer (and yours) is not that questions answer i believe.

Comment: Unfortunately not seeming to work for me; having issues with all the answers (I appreciate all of them, btw). Just stays on the first image upon clicking the button.

Comment: @JackAylett Take a look at my updated answer and keep in mind that it is based on your button having an `id` of `btnChange`.

Answer (score 2):

For achieve your scenario we have to use of counter flag to assign a next image. so we can go throw it.

We can make it more simple

```
var cnt=1;
function changeImage(){
    cnt++;
    document.getElementById("image").src=  = "image" + cnt + ".png";        
}
```

Comment: `cnt` needs to start at 2, otherwise the first click of the button will not change the image, unless you move `cnt++` so that it is prior to the `src` assignment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks you are right, I made it correct

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function changeImage(){
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.src = img.src == 'image1.png' ? "image2.png" : "image3.png";
}
```

Comment: Just seems to skip from the first image to the third image. :/

Answer (score 1):

Just use an if statement to determine what the image's source currently is, like so:

```
function changeImage(){
    var imageSource = document.getElementById("image").src;
    if (imageSource == "image1.png"){
        imageSource = "image2.png";
    }
    else if (imageSource == "image2.png"){
        imageSource = "image3.png";
    }
    else {
        imageSource = "image1.png";
    }
}
```

This should make the image rotate between 3 different image files (`image1.png`, `image2.png` and `image3.png`). Bear in mind this will only work if you have a finite number of image files that you want to rotate through, otherwise you'd be better off using counters.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code if you make it as a cyclic:

**JS**

```
    var imgArray = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"];


        function changeImage(){
            var img = document.getElementById("image").src.split("/"),
                src = img[img.length-1];                        

                idx =   imgArray.indexOf(src);
                if(idx == imgArray.length - 1)      {
                    idx = 0;
                }
                else{
                    idx++;
                }
                document.getElementById("image").src = imgArray[idx];                   
        }
```

**html**

```
<button onclick=changeImage();>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
function changeImage(){
  document.getElementById("image").attr("src","image2.png");
}
```